# android nkd no include path in which to search for limits.h #include_next <limits.h>

Tags: android, android-ndk, x264

When i build the x264 ndk library , i face a problem .
I've compiled both in window and liunx environment.i got the same mistakes...

like this:

```
In file included 
from c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\
aarch64-linux-android-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib\gcc\aarch64-linux-android\4.9.x\include-fixed\syslimits.h:7:0,
from c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\
aarch64-linux-android-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib\gcc\aarch64-linux-android\4.9.x\include-fixed\limits.h:34,
from ./common/common.h:123,
from ./x264cli.h:30,
from ./input/input.h:31,
from ./filters/video/video.h:29,
from ./filters/video/depth.c:26:
c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\aarch64-linux-android-4.9\
prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib\gcc\aarch64-linux-android\4.9.x\include-fixed\limits.h:168:61: 
error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
#include_next <limits.h>  /* recurse down to the real one */

make: *** [.depend] Error 1
```

Here is my script:

```
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64
CC=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/aarch64-linux-android-gcc-4.9.x
#CXX=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/aarch64-linux-android-g++
CROSS_PREFIX=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/aarch64-linux-android-
EXTRA_CFLAGS="-march=armv8-a -D__ANDROID__"
EXTRA_LDFLAGS="-nostdlib"

./configure --prefix=$PREFIX \
        --host=arm-linux \
        --sysroot=$SYSROOT \
        --cross-prefix=$CROSS_PREFIX \
        --extra-cflags="$EXTRA_CFLAGS" \
        --extra-ldflags="$EXTRA_LDFLAGS" \
        --enable-pic \
        --enable-static \
        --enable-strip \
        --disable-cli \
        --disable-win32thread \
        --disable-avs \
        --disable-swscale \
        --disable-lavf \
        --disable-ffms \
        --disable-gpac \
        --disable-lsmash \
        --disable-asm \
        --disable-opencl
```

does anyone know how to solve it? thanks every much.

Comment: Did you get hte answer? Are you able to compile x264 for Android ?

Comment: I followed https://yesimroy.gitbooks.io/android-note/content/compile_x264_for_android.html and I run into the same issue. Are you able to compile x264 for Android ? If yes: how to manage it ?

Answer (score 1):

To build with latest NDK You need to use --deprecated-headers while creating standalone toolchain.

Some additional info: [NDK unified headers](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/ndk-r15-release/docs/UnifiedHeaders.md)

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when you use recent versions of android ndk. Please, use older versions like android ndk r13b. I have successfully built on my mac machine using **android ndk r13b**.

Link given below:

https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r13b-darwin-x86_64.zip

Please, use one specific to your platform.

You can also follow this link https://osburneblog.wordpress.com/2017/06/01/cross-compiling-ffmpeg-and-libx264-for-android/ know more about build process.